# Global name 'pk' is not defined django

Tags: python, django

Hi i have a problem like in topic title.

I have my world detail - here i have a list of countries inside this world.
I would like to delete a country only from only this world, not generally and after that automatically return to this world.

view my_world:

```
def my_world(request, pk):
    world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'game/my_world.html', {'world': world})

def delete_country(request, world_pk, country_pk):
    world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=pk)
    country = get_object_or_404(Country, pk=pk)
    world.country.remove(country)
    return redirect("my_world", pk=world.pk)
```

Error says it is about line

```
world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=pk)
```

in template

```
{% url 'game.views.delete_country' world_pk=world.pk country_pk=country.pk %}
```

url.py

```
url(r'^world/(?P<world_pk>\d+)/(?P<country_pk>\d+)/$', views.delete_country, name='delete_country'),
```

models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name of country", max_length=100, default="Australia")
    number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="number of country", default="1")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class World(models.Model):
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="New Map", max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

How to repair this error?

edit:

NoReverseMatch at /world/31/12/

> Reverse for 'my_world' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{'pk': 31}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

```
return redirect("my_world", pk=world.pk)
```

Comment: Don't you need `get_object_or_404(World, pk=world_pk)`? E.g. in the second view you are not passing an argument named `pk`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, the error cannot be anymore obvious, in your function `delete_country` you don't have `pk` as a parameter, but you did:

```
def delete_country(request, world_pk, country_pk):
    world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=pk)
```

Maybe you try to do `world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=world_pk)`

**Edit:**:

You are using the wrong way to return `redirect`. `redirect` is expecting a url that it can redirect to, but you are giving it a function name. If your `my_world` function is also have a url name as `my_world`, you should use `reverse` to derive the url from that:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def delete_country(request, world_pk, country_pk):
    world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=pk)
    country = get_object_or_404(Country, pk=pk)
    world.country.remove(country)
    return redirect(reverse('my_world', args=(world.pk,)))
```

Check out the [redirect documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) and [reverse documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls). It might/might not make sense immediately, but if they don't, try to slow down and read/search for some examples as well.

Comment: And similarly `country = get_object_or_404(Country, pk=country_pk)` on the following line.

Comment: Thank you, solution was so simple, true... but now when i am redirecting to world site after removing i get this error: edit:

NoReverseMatch at /world/31/12/

> Reverse for 'my_world' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
> '{'pk': 31}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

    return redirect("my_world", pk=world.pk)   I think it is about url but i don't know how to change it, i tried to delete (?P<country_pk>\d+) from url but does not work.

Comment: Thank you! Now i see this error was because i had a typo only, but i will use your solution, looks better i think and i will learn something new.

Answer (score 2):

There is no variable named `pk` that's why it is throwing the error. Those methods are called in url. Only `world_pk` and and `country_pk` are defined.

Use `world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=world_pk)`

or `world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=country_pk)`